# Is there an R package for connecting to U2 / Universe / PICK?

Tags: r, universe, u2

I've searched a bit this morning and didn't seem to find anything. I just need to read some files into an R data frame.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of work, but you can arrange for ODBC access to your U2 database, and then there are several approaches to connecting from R.  Perhaps https://db.rstudio.com/odbc/.

https://www.intl-spectrum.com/Article/r202/Installing_and_Using_UniVerse_ODBC_A_Quickstart

Has a good walk through of the process, and there are of course docs on the Rocket web site.